# interpret the performance of my model from confusion matrix

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

how I can interpret the performance of my model from this matrix[image]

Comment: Can you share with us how the image was generated?

Comment: I think the `True label` and `Predicted label` are misplaced since the values in a row doesn't add up to 100%.

Comment: Can you post a matrix with the actual values instead of the ratios?

Comment: Not a programming question, please ask this in the AI Stackexchange instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to evaluate through precision, recall and f-score. precision is defined as True positive/ True positives + False Positives
and precision is True positive/ True positives + False Negatives. F-score is an mean of both precision and recall.

There is a way clearer than this. You can get the precision, recall and f-score from this function using the `classification_report()` from sklearn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_predicted))
```

Please check your y_predicted that its the right classes values before you pass it to this function you may need to use `np.argmax()`

An example of what the function will return something like this:

```
          precision    recall   f-score
class1       0.79       0.98      0.80
class2       0.89       0.79      0.82
```

You can find more about this function [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)